# SwiftUI - Group NSFetchRequest by date to display in list with sections

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I'm building a SwiftUI app where it shows a list of values containing their associated date and duration. At the moment the `ContentView` is just listing all the values (date ascending).

What I would like to achieve is so that entities are grouped by date and into their relevant sections, for example:

**Current**

- Section: "date"

  - Duration: 50, Date: 1st Jan
  - Duration: 48, Date: 1st Jan
  - Duration: 21, Date: 2nd Jan
  - Duration: 57, Date: 3rd Jan

**Aim**

- Section: "1st Jan"

  - Duration: 50, Date: 1st Jan
  - Duration: 48, Date: 1st Jan
- Section: "2nd Jan"

  - Duration: 21, Date: 2nd Jan
- Section: "3rd Jan"

  - Duration: 57, Date: 3rd Jan

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks.

**Code**

```
// MARK: - ContentView

struct ContentView: View {

    // MARK: - Variables

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: EntityCore.fetch()) var entities

    // MARK: - Body

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Date")) {
                    ForEach(entities) { (entity) in
                        EntityView(entity: entity)

                    }
                }

            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
             .navigationBarTitle(Text("Entities"))

        }
    }
}

// MARK: - PlankCore

public class EntityCore: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {

    // MARK: - Variables

    @NSManaged public var duration: Int64
    @NSManaged public var date: Date?

    // MARK: - Fetch

    static func fetch() -> NSFetchRequest<EntityCore> {

        let request = EntityCore.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<EntityCore>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]

        return request

    }
}
```

Comment: This has been answered in a newer question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180698/how-to-properly-group-a-list-fetched-from-coredata-by-date

Comment: See how @SectionedFetchRequest can help you with sectioning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840941